# Pass string parameter when running Invoke-SqlCmd?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a stored procedure with a parameter of type `nvarchar(max)`. And I need to call it in PowerShell.

```
// $s can be a long string with all kind of charaters, ', new line, etc.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server "exec MyProc '$s'"
```

However, the above calling doesn't work well when `$s` has `'` (I know I can handle this case by replacing `'`' to `''` but) or `\n\r`, etc. Also it has the risk of SQL injection.

Is it a way to invoke the stored without string concatenation?

Comment: The dollar sign variable does not get replaced inside a single quote.  Try : Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Server "exec MyProc '" + $s + "'"

Answer (score 2):

To avoid SQL injections you will need to do parameterized SQL queries. Unfortunately `Invoke-Sqlcmd` does not support something like this!
Even with useing the `-Variable` flag will not prevent SQL injection (see https://powershellstation.com/2016/01/05/invoke-sqlcmd-considered-harmful/)

Instead you will need to use a Powershell module such as SQLHelper, which uses the .Net Package "System.Data.SQLClient".

**NOTE:** This does **not** work with Powershell 7 or greater as `System.Data.SQLClient` was removed from the System directory and needs to be installed via Nuget. Therefor the name also changed to `Microsoft.Data.SQLClient`.
I wasn't able to find a Powershell Module yet that supports parameterized SQL queries in Powershell 7

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-Variable` parameter for `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.

```
$vars = @("VAR1=$s")
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance Server "exec MyProc @procParam=`$(VAR1)" -Variable $vars
```

This will automatically escape special characters and avoid SQL injection.

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) you need to state the parameter you are passing to for stored procedures. That is what `@procParam` is in the above code.

Note: The backtick dollar sign (`` `$ ``) is important as otherwise the string will be expanded before it reaches the function, which will result in an error. You could also switch the quotes to single quotes, which would make the backtick not required.

## EDIT

It is important to note that `-Variable` only accepts a String array. This means to delcare a single value, you must use the syntax `@()` to denote an array (as in the example).

Reference: [`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#examples)

Comment: Just tried **$v = "x'x";
$sa = "V1='$v'";
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select `$(V1) as V1" -ServerInstance server -Variable $sa**, it didn't work.

Comment: Try without the single quotes in `$sa`. Also, `$sa` **must be a string array**. To force it to a string array, use `$sa = @("V1=$v")`. You can add multiple variables by adding more strings to `$sa`

Comment: Removing `'` in `$sa` and convert it to a string array doesn't help. It seems it will just construst a string of `select x'x as V1` using `$sa`.

Comment: Try using the quotes and the array conversion